# Name and usage of this symbol?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Interesting names for mathematical symbols came up in conversation over coffee. I recalled a symbol that was commonly called "washing machine", looks like:

$\begin{bmatrix}0 &  & &\\ \\ &&\Huge\circ && &\\\\ \\\end{bmatrix}$

(matrix brackets, zero upper left, large zero/circle in middle (I recall center circle as much larger, but could not get that rendered in LaTex).

A half hour of Google searching for "washing machine" & "mathematical symbol" and the such leads to nonsense.

IIRC, it had to do with linear algebra perhaps.

Here's hoping someone recognizes it.

Thanks.

Comment: Without any further context information this looks like a strangely drawn zero matrix, but I guess you would not ask in that case.

Comment: It could also have been an attempt at a block diagonal matrix with some blocks zero... that would explain the difference in sizes of zeroes used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a zero matrix.  The central big zero is for all elements but the top left one.  The top left zero is more generally nonzero.  The name comes from it looking like a front-loading clothes washer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Descriptive_informalities

Comment: Bravo! Was driving me nuts... thanks so much.